# A few questions regarding mutivariable limits.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I know that if we take the limit of a multivariable function along different paths and we arrive at different limits then the limit does not exists.

However would it be correct to say that;

If we take the limit along a path and the limit exists yet if 
we take the limit along another path and the limit does not exist then 
the limit does not exist??

This screams TRUE, but I like to tread carefully.

also, say if we would like to find the limit of a function at some point $(a,b)$ could I let $x=a$ and $y = b+n$ and see what happens as $n \rightarrow 0$ then $x=a+n$ and $y = b$ as $n \rightarrow 0$ then if we get different limits the limit at $(a,b)$ does not exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by "if we take the limit along another path and the limit does not exist"? If this means that when $(x,y)\to(a,b)$ along some path, we get $\lim f(x,y)=\pm\infty$, and along some other path we get
$$\lim f(x,y)=L$$
then the limit does not exist. You are correct in all your other statements.

The $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of a multivariable limit of a function $f(\mathbf{x})$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is that the limit $\lim_{\mathbf{x}\to\mathbf{a}} f(\mathbf{x})=L$ exists if and only if for all $\epsilon>0$ there exists a $\delta>0$ such that
$$|f(\mathbf{x})-L|<\epsilon$$
whenever
$$0<|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{a}|<\delta$$
where $\mathbf{x}=(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)$ and $\mathbf{a}=(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n)$ are points in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and
$$|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{a}|=\sqrt{(x_1-a_1)^2+(x_2-a_2)^2+\ldots+(x_n-a_n)^2}$$
is the distance between the two points.

For $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{R}^3$, this corresponds to the function getting arbitrarily close to $L$ whenever we restrict the domain to a circle or sphere around the point $\mathbf{a}$.

Comment: For example, if along one path I get $xsin(1/x)$ and along another i get $\pi sin(1/x)$? then in the first case the limit as x tends to 0 is 0 and in the second case the limit does not exist?

Comment: Yes, then the limit does not exist because setting $\epsilon=\pi-1$ means that there is always a point within $\delta$ distance of $(x,y)=(0,0)$ such that $\pi\sin(1/x)>\epsilon$

Comment: The limit in this case is meant to be evaluated at $(0,\pi)$, but I didnt include ANY details, and I am assuming this holds. That's why I was being quite general in my question. Thanks for the help though

Comment: If your function is $f(x,y) = y\sin(1/x)$ then the point $(0,\pi)$ doesn't lie on the path of $y=x$. It would be on the line $y=x+\pi$ and you would approach it along $f(x,x+\pi) = (x+\pi)\sin(1/x)$, which has no limit. Regardless, you are correct in your understanding of a limit.